# Disabling an ADD Button in row of Datatables and Enabling it By clicking other ADD Button in different Row JQUERY

Tags: jquery, datatables

**Code for the creating the DataTable**

```
var MCCntrctrTable = S$('#tblMCSelVndr').DataTable({
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "aoColumns": [
                            { "sTitle": "Vendor ID", "mData": "VendorID", "sWidth": "19%" },
                            { "sTitle": "Contractor Legal Name", "mData": "CNTRCTR_NM", "sWidth": "40%" },
                            //{ "sTitle": "Work Type", "mData": "CNTRCT_WorkTyp", "sWidth": "20%" },
                            { "sTitle": "Address ", "mData": "ADDR", "sWidth": "40%" },
                            { "sTitle": "", "mData": "CNTROR_ADDR_ID", "sWidth": "1%" },
                            { "sTitle": " ", "mRender": function (data, type, full) { return '<button>ADD</button>' }, "sWidth": "10%", "sClass": "center" }
        ],
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
        "bSort": true,
        "aaSorting": [],
        "bStateSave": true,
        "data": data,
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "columnDefs": [
       {
           "targets": [3],
           "visible": false
       }, ]

    });
```

**Event Called when clicking the button in row**

```
S$('#tblMCSelVndr tbody').on('click', 'button', function (e) {
        debugger;
        var data = MCCntrctrTable.row(S$(this).parents('tr')).data();
        //MCCntrctrTable.eq(0).attr('disabled')
        newCNTRList = [];
        if (data) {
            var cntrctrToAdd = {
                CNTRCNTRCTRID: '',
                CntrctrAddID: data.CNTROR_ADDR_ID,
                VedorID: data.VendorID,
                LegalName: data.CNTRCTR_NM,
                CntrctrAddr: data.ADDR,
                ProgID: data.ProgID,
                CatID: data.CLCat_ID,
                SelMethod: S$("#SelectionMethod").val(),
                SelMethodName: S$("#SelectionMethod  option:selected").text()
            }

            debugger;

            newCNTRList.push(cntrctrToAdd);



        }

        //remove contractor from dataTable
        S$(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
```

For the first time when i click the add button in the row of table, the ADD button of that specific row gets disabled. 
Now if i click a different add in other row, the previous disabled button should be enabled. For that i have to find the button in the table which is disabled. 
i tried several possibilities such as

```
S$('#tblMCSelVndr tbody').eq(0).attr('disabled')
S$('#tblMCSelVndr tbody').find('tr td disabled')
```

None of them work!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`:disabled`](https://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/) pseudo selector. To remove the `disabled` behaviour, you can use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
S$('#tblMCSelVndr').find('button:disabled').prop('disabled', false);
```

Comment: That's finding the right button which has attribute disabled. but in order to remove the attribute i am trying `S$('#tblMCSelVndr').find('button[disabled]').removeAttr();`                     and it doesn't work

Comment: @CoderUnknown Glad to have helped.